# Get contents by class names using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup module, how can I get data of a `div` tag whose class name is `feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent`? Is it:

```
soup.class['feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent']
```

or:

```
soup.find_all('class')
```

This is the HTML source:

```
<div class="feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent">
    <div class="feeditembodyandfooter">
         <div class="feeditembody">
         <span>The actual data is some where here</span>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and this is the Python code:

```
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 html_doc = open('home.jsp.html', 'r')

 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
 class="feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, maybe it's too much for this simple thing but it works:

```
def match_class(target):
    target = target.split()
    def do_match(tag):
        try:
            classes = dict(tag.attrs)["class"]
        except KeyError:
            classes = ""
        classes = classes.split()
        return all(c in classes for c in target)
    return do_match

html = """<div class="feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent">
<div class="feeditembodyandfooter">
<div class="feeditembody">
<span>The actual data is some where here</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>"""

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10

matches = soup.findAll(match_class("feeditembody"))
for m in matches:
    print m
    print "-"*10
```

Comment: `classes = dict(tag.attrs).get('class', '')` is much shorter than the `try` `except` block and it's functionality is the same.

Comment: @DoronCohen is `dict()` needed? Seems to work without.

Comment: @Mark I get an exception without the `dict()` because it's a list `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. Also, this answer assumes Beautiful Soup 3 (might be why you're seeing different results), you should probably be using version 4 and use the other answer.

Comment: Ow yeah I'm using 4, that may be it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Beautiful Soup 4 treats the value of the "class" attribute as a list rather than a string, meaning jadkik94's solution can be simplified:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                   

def match_class(target):                                                        
    def do_match(tag):                                                          
        classes = tag.get('class', [])                                          
        return all(c in classes for c in target)                                
    return do_match                                                             

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)                                                      
print soup.find_all(match_class(["feeditemcontent", "cxfeeditemcontent"]))
```

Answer (score 11):

`soup.findAll("div", class_="feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent")`

So, If I want to get all div tags of class header `<div class="header">` from stackoverflow.com, an example with BeautifulSoup would be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests 

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(html)

tags = soup.findAll("div", class_="header")
```

It is already in bs4 [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class).

Answer (score 6):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
f = open('a.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f) 
list = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id':'abc def'})
print list
```

Answer (score 3):

```
soup.find("div", {"class" : "feeditemcontent cxfeeditemcontent"})
```

Comment: or soup.findAll if you want more than one (use the same arguments)

Comment: I wouldn't really use that code for obvious reasons. Check my answer. There's a related bug report.

Comment: Can you explain why you downvoted my solution?  It works flawlessly.

Comment: The point is your code would work flawlessly only for this **very** specific HTML string. Simplest example of when your code would fail is when `class=cxfeeditemcontent feeditemcontent`. General point is: `class="a b c"` should be treated as a **set** containing a,b,c and never like an ordered **list**.

Answer (score 0):

Check this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/410304

As you can see, Beautiful soup can not really understand `class="a b"` as two classes `a` and `b`.

However, as it appears in the first comment there, a simple regexp should suffice. In your case:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
for x in soup.findAll("div",{"class":re.compile(r"\bfeeditemcontent\b")}):
    print "result: ",x
```

Note: That has been fixed in the recent beta. I haven't gone through the docs of the recent versions, may be you could do that. Or if you want to get it working using the older version, you could use the above.