# Inserting HTML into an html file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a file which contains links to different pages. I want to insert them into my HTML file beneath a `div` with `id="links"`. To be clear, the `div` already exists, so I don't want to create a new tag anywhere.

My python and HTML attempt are shown

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="links">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myhtml.html'),'html.parser')
div = soup.select("#links")
print(div)

content = '<a href="abcd.com">Link</a>'
div.append(BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser'))

print(div)
print (soup)
```

Note- I have seen the following pages but they did not address my question
[Insert HTML into an element with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056240/insert-html-into-an-element-with-beautifulsoup)
[Append markup string to a tag in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984933/append-markup-string-to-a-tag-in-beautifulsoup)
[Edit and create HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355225/edit-and-create-html-file-using-python)
[Using BeautifulSoup to modify HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775930/using-beautifulsoup-to-modify-html)
[Get contents by class names using Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331071/get-contents-by-class-names-using-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup.select()` will return list of `elements`.To append tag inside a single element you need to use `select_one()`

Just replace

`div = soup.select("#links")`

to

`div = soup.select_one("#links")`

**Code**:

```
html='''<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="links">
    </div>
</body>
</html>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
div = soup.select_one("#links")
print(div)

content = '<a href="abcd.com">Link</a>'
div.append(BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser'))

print(div)
print (soup)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Could you please provide an explanation as well to why does that work and why not the code given in question. It would be helpful to future viewers as well.

Comment: @user185887 : Thanks mate just added it.